# Do I need `__stdcall` in `std::unique_ptr` deleter?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, unique-ptr, stdcall

I want to manage a WinAPI function pair via `std::unique_ptr`:

```cpp
#include <memory>

int* __stdcall construct(){ return new int{5}; }
void __stdcall destruct(int* v){ delete v; }

int main() {
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<int, void(&)(int*)>;
    Ptr v(construct(), destruct);
}
```

When I build a 64-bit binary with MSVC 19.33, the code works. If I build a 32-bit binary, then there is an error.

- [Live example](https://www.godbolt.ms/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%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%2BQlDUdtdC4fRDGMLNLH0BDu0geZUDNDJuw4LsYKqRxnAgVwRj8SQMUCBh0B6EoykrPI0gkzJPGaEA5PUgoGGUvo4nWWwxPaBhOmGbScj0tpNKsiZimMtSPi6GTdPktyGiM6YTPmBRcxWPQVUwVYeDjBM2x/dMOF3B0RQURduXXWt1l2CBM0saxrVwQgSH2Mx1lY3YPDnehVQLWZeGLN9ZnLSsawbZq6ybWDW1ITCMV7ZNU1irsez7OrSEHEdZwnCrp0DMcJv6Rdl1XdcXgMTkPm3B1pAPI8TzPH8L2YYhX1vMd7wIJ8X3bD92O/VM/3EvBAOE1MQLAiDuCgwQYPbeDEOQjBVlTdDMPe7DcIIoiSLI5NC34KjvlozbZEUFR1B/XQAgMIwUE4mwft40E00EgRhNE%2BxNJcRSPNY4JJhU/pWJSDSMip/TNN81TWPsmpxhZrmOnGdn6cGdybL8TmBdplyuACoLaKLGFwtjZsOETUhet4WLVA2xLkrXeJqxW8MCAyrKrC43Y8qISqipKsrZut9YzGqoatHq0gEEwJgsDiAn2t4LqevbfrbEG2rXYaqs0paxtlfWaK%2Bs7F2ldGlOkEWAgknAqbxvncJWFWLXJB15AUv1swd12fChC4B1q3iXhMHwK3ST0WHhHhiREcEZGmLRvQkSQpIsOV1X1Y7DgH3AzPjdQKhdni4vS7Sk2ZvnQriudsPS1ICtI%2Bj5rlY6gO1aDxPu17LeB2HCA06nrOKGm8rYjzthOELxe9ercvK%2Br2v68CJuJAW6sTbtRcQdE2491RqmdGpAB5MCHiDEe8cNacEnhncCuxZ7z21iwJKJdP6Gw%2BCvJ%2BDsnY1X7PMD2Xt%2Bi%2BxbP7EA3UT4xTPqHShO9GpR33lWWOKDx4ULqpFDgZg%2BHB0vvMQCx4Mi6SAA)

```
example.cpp
<source>(8): error C2660: 'std::unique_ptr<int,void (__cdecl &)(int *)>::unique_ptr': function does not take 2 arguments
C:/data/msvc/14.33.31631/include\memory(3291): note: see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<int,void (__cdecl &)(int *)>::unique_ptr'
Compiler returned: 2
```

It works with both if I explicitly name the `__stdcall` in `std::unique_ptr<int, void(__stdcall&)(int*)>`, so I assume it is part of the function signature.

Why is there this difference in 32 and 64 bit? Is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: The [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) probably already provides what you're trying to implement here.

Comment: There is only one possible calling convention for x64, so the compiler just uses that always.

Comment: "*so I assume it is part of the function signature*" - yes, a calling convention is part of the signature. If no convention is specified, `__cdecl` is the default (unless the compiler is configured otherwise). But in 64-bit, there is only 1 convention available (and no keyword for it), so all other conventions (`__cdecl`, `__stdcall`, etc) are simply ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-170)

> On ARM and x64 processors, __stdcall is accepted and ignored by the
> compiler; on ARM and x64 architectures, by convention, arguments are
> passed in registers when possible, and subsequent arguments are passed
> on the stack.

So `__stdcall` is ignored by the 64-bit compiler but meaningful only for the 32-bit compiler.